# Como ordenar una tabla responsiva con php

Tags: php, html, ordenamiento, table

El problema que tengo es que al intentar ordenar la tabla  no puedo ya que esta paginado y se me interponen las querys .

y no logro poder ordenar las filas id o nombre de forma ascendente o descendente  a través de una etiqueta HTML a .

He visto varios videos pero no lo he logrado.

Disculpe si es una pregunta muy básica

```
          <div class="table-responsive table-hover table-dark" id="Tabla-productos">
            <br>
            
              <table class="table ">
                  <thead class="text-muted table-dark">
                        <th class="text-center">  ID</th>
                        <th class="text-center"> Nombre Producto</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Descripcion</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Marca</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Foto</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Precio</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
                     
                        
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                    <?php
                    if(!$_GET){
                      header('location: index.php?pagina=1');
                    }

                    $contador_paginacion=  ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$articulos_por_pagina;
                 
                    $start_from = ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$articulos_por_pagina;

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM productos  LIMIT $start_from, $articulos_por_pagina";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                   //while($row =$productos_de_la_pag->fetch_assoc()){ 
                 foreach($result as $row):
                
                     ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Producto'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Descripcion'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Marca'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center "> <img  width="100px" src="data:image/jpg;base64 ,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Foto']);?> " /></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Precio'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Cantidad'];?></td>
                        <!-- pasamos los datos de esa fila a travez del campo id -->
                      
                      </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  </tbody>
              </table>

          
          </div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Logre ordenarlos con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php


  
  $consulta= "SELECT * FROM productos";
  $guardar = $conn->query($consulta);


$cant_filas= mysqli_num_rows($guardar);
$articulos_por_pagina=6;

$paginas= ceil( $cant_filas/$articulos_por_pagina);

if(isset($_GET['Producto'])){
  $nombre = $_GET['Producto'];
}else{
 $nombre= 'ASC';
}
if(isset($_GET['idcolumn'])){
  $idcolumn = $_GET['idcolumn'];
}else{
 $idcolumn= 'id';
}

//$ordenamiento= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY $idcolumn $nombre");
?>



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 
  <body>
    <body>
        
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../Home/home.html">
                    <img
                      src="../../img/logo check inventory.png"
                      alt=""
                      width="100"
                      height="100"
                      class="d-inline-block align-text-center logo-image"
                    />
                    Check Inventory
                  </a>
              
                </div>
              
                <div class="d-flex">
                  
                 <a href="busqueda.php"> <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success" type="submit">Buscar</button></a>
                  <a href="../../Home/home.html" ,<?php session_abort();?> <button type="button"class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary ">Salir</button></a>
                 
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
   

          <div class="titulo">
              <h1>Inventariado de productos</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="table-responsive table-hover table-dark" id="Tabla-productos">
            <br>
            <?php 
              if($nombre=='DESC'){
                   $nombre = 'ASC' ;
              } else if($nombre = 'ASC'){
                $nombre='DESC';
              }
             //?if :no?>
              <table class="table ">
                  <thead class="text-muted table-dark">
                        <th class="text-center"> <a href="?idcolumn=id&Producto=<?php echo $nombre?>&pagina= <?php echo $_GET['pagina'] ?>"> ID</a></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><a href="?idcolumn=Producto&Producto=<?php echo $nombre?>&pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina'] ?>"> Nombre Producto</a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Descripcion</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Marca</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Foto</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Precio</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
                     
                        
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                    <?php
                    if(!$_GET['pagina']){
                      header('location: index.php?pagina=1');
                    }

                    $contador_paginacion=  ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$articulos_por_pagina;
                 
                    $start_from = ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$articulos_por_pagina;

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY $idcolumn $nombre LIMIT $start_from, $articulos_por_pagina";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                   //while($row =$productos_de_la_pag->fetch_assoc()){ 
                 foreach($result as $row):
                
                     ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Producto'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Descripcion'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Marca'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center "> <img  width="100px" src="data:image/jpg;base64 ,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Foto']);?> " /></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Precio'];?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['Cantidad'];?></td>
                        <!-- pasamos los datos de esa fila a travez del campo id -->
                      
                      </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  </tbody>
              </table>

              
              <nav aria-label="Page navigation example " class="paginas">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']<$paginas? 'disabled': '' ?>"><a class="page-link" href=" <?php echo 'index.php?pagina='.$_GET['pagina']-1 ?> ">Anterior</a></li>
   <?php for ($i=0; $i < $paginas; $i++):  ?>
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']==$i+1  ? 'active' : ''  ?>"> <!--esta linea de codigo php muestra en que pagina estamos -->
      <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $i+1?>"><?php echo $i+1?></a></li>
    <?php endfor ?>
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']>=$paginas? 'disabled': '' ?>"><a class="page-link" href="<?php echo 'index.php?pagina='.$_GET['pagina']+1 ?>">Siguiente</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
          </div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```